# How To Access Props In a functional components

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have some problem with component
When i use props i get same data in all of mates, but in `GET_ODD` action data is different 
1)now how i can fix this porblem ?
2)how i can set interval for odd changes ? `if this.props.odd.ad_time < nextProps.odd.ad_time` change the odd in curenet props

json data for each odd : 
{

```
"id": "24854545",
"home_od": "1.002",
"draw_od": "51.000",
"away_od": "51.000",
"ss": "3-1",
"time_str": "87",
"add_time": "1537706413"
```

### }

reducer :

```
const initialState = {
    odd: {}
};

function Markets(state = initialState, action) {

  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_ODD:
            return {
                ...state,
               ...action.odd
            };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default Markets
```

Markets action :

```
var marketsRESTRepository = new MarketsRESTRepository();

export const GET_ODD = "GET_ODD";
export function getOdd(odd) {
  return {
    type: GET_ODD,
    odd
  }
}



export function getAsyncOdd(eventId) {
  return function (dispatch) {
    marketsRESTRepository.getById(eventId).then(odd => {
      dispatch(getOdd({odd}));
    });
  }
}
```

[Action Odd data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNq5j.png)
[same results for odds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5McN.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the market component try this :

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { getAsyncOdd } from "../../actions/markets.actions";

export class Markets extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
super(props); 
   this.state = {
       odds: {}
   };
}

componentDidMount(){
  this.props.getOdd(this.props.eventId);
  this.setState({this.props.odd})
}
componentWillRecieveProps(nextProps) {
  if(this.state.odds!==nextprops.odd){
      this.setState({odds: nextprops.odd})
  }
}

  render() {

return (
  <React.Fragment> 
    <span>{this.state.odds.home_od}</span>
    <span>{this.state.odds.draw_od}</span>
    <span>{this.state.odds.away_od}</span>
 </React.Fragment>
);
  }
}
function mapStateToProps({ markets }) {
  return {
   odd: markets.odd
  }
}
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
   return {
   getOdd: (eventId) => dispatch(getAsyncOdd(eventId))
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Markets)
```

Comment: `fromRequireContextWithGlobalFallback.js:19 Error: Module build failed: SyntaxError: this is a reserved word (16:17)` of this line : `this.setState({this.props.odd})`

Comment: i changed code to this error solved   `this.setState({odds: this.props.odd})`, but steal state is empey and code not work

Comment: try changing your
   const mapStateToProps=state=> ({
       odd: state.Markets.odd
   })

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is with your reducer,

Why are you spreading the action? Since you are accessing it this way,

```
<span>{this.props.odd.home_od}</span>
```

Change it to this,

```
       return {
            ...state,
            add : action.odd
        };
```

Comment: if i change it i get error : Module build failed: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token, expected , (16:18)` of this line of reducer:  `action.odd`

Comment: i think propblem is in the component , cuz action get data for each event id

Answer (score 0):

You have this:

```
 dispatch(getOdd({odd}));
```

and the getOdd sync action will return this object:

```
{
    type: "GET_ODD",
    odd: {
        odd: { /* data */}
    }
}
```

which in turn will get dumped in the state by the reducer using the spread operator. I think you have to change the approach:

1. keep you getOdd action as is
2. when you call getOdd use it as `getOdd(odd)`. No curly braces.
3. in you reducer, don't use the spread operator for the action. Use a specific key, for example:

   return {
       ...state,
       odd: action.odd 
   }
4. your async action looks good, just add a catch there and add a console.error so you know if something fails

For you 2 question. You can use one of the React life cycle methods to compare the current props and the next props coming and then perform that logic.

I hope it helps!